# how to detect didSelectRowAtIndexPath on managedObjectSelected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I have the following code which is automatically triggered when I tap on a cell

```
- (void)managedObjectSelected:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject {

}
```

but I wanted to deselect a row at the selected indexPath. How do I do so in this method because I don't have any indexPath to work on with. Any ideas? If I add in the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

then  the managedObjectSelected isn't called. Any idea? I basically wanted to call deselectRowAtIndexPath when I tapped on a cell. But to do so I needed the indexPath

Comment: wt u want?? u want to get indexpath of selected row in managedObjectSelected method ??

Comment: yesss, because I wanted to deselect the row when the cell is tapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)managedObjectSelected:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject 
{

  NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

  NSLog(@"%@",myIndexPath.row);
}
```